# sorting folders according to size

Tags: bash, filesystems

I need to free up some space and I started to look for big and useless files and directories. In order to focus on the biggest ones first I do

```
   du --max-depth=1 | sort -n
```

to identify the biggest folders in the current one. This has the drawback that the size is not in "human" units, so it's hard to say how big each folder.

Is there another way to get the size of each folder and then sort them by size and display the size in human units?

Cheers,
Roberto

Comment: `du -h` would print in human readable form

Comment: but then how do I sort it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`du -h` displays sizes in human readable form. You can't sort them, so just apply it on the already sorted files:

```
du --max-depth=1 | sort -n | cut -f2 | xargs du --max-depth=0 -h
```

Note: Doesn't work for directories with spaces in their names. For such a case, replace the `xargs` with the (much slower) loop:

```
while read f ; do du --max-depth=0 -h "$f" ; done
```

Comment: Hi Chroba, thanks for your suggestion. This is simple and effective, just to the point. I just tried it out, it works great. Actually `du` is so slow that the loop is just a small addition ... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since a picture is worth a thousand words, why not do it graphically, using something like http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/index.html ?

[image]

Also, of course remove unneeded package files, temp files, backup files, etc, using something like https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/linux-disk-cleaner/  Run it manually or as a cron jo0b.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words when you're doing it manually. A word is worth a thousand pictures when you're trying to automate something in a script :-) Still, that's not necessarily the case here so good answer.

Comment: Lolx - I saw the others & did wonder if you wanted to script it, but your question seemed to indicate that it was not when you said "display the size in human units". Answer accepted? It's certainly the quickest & easiest way to go about it ;-)

Comment: I'm not the asker so I can't accept it. We'll need to leave that up to Roberto :-)

Comment: Looks like a great tool, but here I am doing this over SSH, so better stick to command-line, if possible. Plus the question might be asked in a OS X context, then I am not sure if your answer is still valid. Thanks a lot anyways for pointing out this tool!

Comment: Thanks for the info about SSH (and the possibility of OS X - I am not very informed about that, but thought that it is basically just a GUI laid over BSD?. Anyway, I am glad to have pointed out a useful tool; there are many such for Linux, and Windows - presumably OS X too. Maybe you should update the question to restrict to command line only?

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally worry about human readable format, you can just use:

```
 du -s * 2>/dev/null | sort -k1 -n
```

to get them in the correct order, then concentrate on the last few.

If you *really* need them in human readable format, you can post-process the output of `du` with something like:

```
du -s * 2>/dev/null | sort -k1 -n | awk '{
    if ($1>999999999) {
        $1 = int($1/1000000000)"G"
    } else {
        if ($1>999999) {
            $1 = int($1/1000000)"M"
        } else {
            if ($1>999) {
                $1 = int($1/1000)"K"
            }
        }
    }
} {print $0}'
```

This modifies the first argument depending on its size, to be in GB, MB, KB or left alone, then prints the modified line.